# when run objective-c with gcc | AppleEvents.h error

Tags: objective-c

here is the console output:

```
➜  daniel-macBook gcc helloWorld.m 
In file included from helloWorld.m:1:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:87:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:14:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:23:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:29:
/Library/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AppleEvents.h:597:165: error: expected function body after function declarator
  ...const AEAddressDesc* target, AEEventClass theAEEventClass, AEEventID theAEEventID, Boolean askUserIfNeeded ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING( __M...
                                                                                                                  ^
/usr/include/Availability.h:216:50: note: expanded from macro '__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING'
    #define __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_osx, _ios) __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_osx
                                                 ^
<scratch space>:84:1: note: expanded from here
__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_14
^
1 error generated.
```

and the resource code *helloworld.m*:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   NSLog (@"hello world");
   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

Quite appreciated if you have any idea to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gcc helloWorld.m -framework Foundation
```

Comment: @Danielzz I did compile & run your example on my mac with `gcc helloWorld.m -framework Foundation` so I think the culprit might be in the environment itself. Do you have `Xcode` or `Xcode command line tools` installed?

Comment: @ Kamil.S Yes, Ive installed with Xcode(10.1), Command line tools for Xcode(10.1) on macOS High Sierra(10.13.6). Actually, it work well yesterday. Is there any way to recover?

Answer (score 0):

Although I still have no idea what operation caused that, I recovered from it successfully trying *reinstall macOS* .